# Origin of "cut a voluntary" meaning "to fall from one's horse when hunting"

Tags: etymology, idioms

It is apparently hunting jargon term meaning to fall off of a horse. Definition below from Dictionary of Jargon (Routledge Revivals) By Jonathon Green:

> **cut a voluntary** v. [Hunting] to fall from one's horse when hunting

It appears in Peter Fleming's 1936 travel book "News from Tartary", though apparently not directly related to hunting:

> Kini, in fact, cut a voluntary while galloping after the camels.

What could be the origin of this?

Comment: https://www.oed.com/dictionary/cut_v?tl=true#7592932 suggests a first recorded use in 1863 for falling without sufficient cause

Comment: It's rather ironic that the voluntary is in fact involuntary.

Comment: I'd guess it was intended as a joke. The OED has this sense of "voluntary" but doesn't offer any explanation. There is a rare sense of "voluntary" meaning a voluntary action but the only citation is 1652 so it doesn't seem connected (its use would be ironic). There are however several other senses of voluntary, for voluntary, freely-chosen, or extemporary pieces of music, writing, etc. But I'd only be guessing if I theorised further.

Comment: I think it referred originally to a conscripted soldier's *self-inflicted* injury (i.e. to avoid death in battle).  It had nothing to do with hunting.

Comment: [When I saw your name, I thought of Under Milkwood. :)]

Comment: I think the term is probably "voluntary gallop" which seems to refer to the horse taking control? There are some google book hits which predate the US civil war that seem to imply the rider was thrown or the horse spooked and took off without being under control

Comment: Since you already have an answer, I will just add what’s missing: The *OED*’s parent entry for *voluntary* under which *cut a voluntary* falls is: *Free will or choice; **something done or created spontaneously or without direction**.* When you stupidly fall off a horse, you can’t justify it by blaming the horse or the stirrups or the jump. You did it all by yourself!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Voluntary** is a substantive. -> an action done of one's own volition.

OED

> **Voluntary** (n.)
>
> **I.7. A parting of a rider from his or her horse without sufficient cause; an unwarranted fall.** Frequently **to cut a voluntary.**
>
> 1863 A conscript, who could keep his saddle, through an entire day,
> without ‘taking a voluntary’, was considered..a credit to the
> regiment.
> *G. A. Lawrence, Border & Bastille ii 33*
>
> 1883 They will say I cut a voluntary... The stirrup-leather alone was
> to blame. **E. Kennard, Right Sort xxi**
>
> 1890 The number of ‘voluntaries’ which are ever taking place in the
> hunting field. *Field 8 February 177*

The sense of the verb “to cut” [now rare] is given at

**OED**

> VI.25. **To perform or execute (an action, gesture, or display of a
> grotesque, striking, or notable kind): chiefly in certain established
> phrases,** as to cut a caper at caper n.2 b, to cut a dash at dash n.1
> 10, to cut a figure, to cut a joke, **to
> cut a voluntary at voluntary n. C.I.7.** Also, to cut an antic, to cut a curvet, to cut a flourish; to cut faces, to make grimaces, distort the features.
>
> 1811 I cut one of my best opera flourishes. *W. Irving, Life & Letters
> (1864) vol. I. xvii. 262*
>
> 1835 Two of us..saw a fellow..cutting queer antics.
> *W. Irving, Tour on Prairies xxii*

For "unwarranted" = unwarranted by an exterior agency

> OED [un]warranted
>
> **9.a. To give (a person) warrant or authority, authorize (to do something); to authorize, sanction (a course of action).**
>
> 1859 What most perplexes me is some names in the list of those who
> have warranted this step. *Keble in J. O. Johnston, Life & Letters J.
> Parry Liddon (1904) 47*

Added 20240104

If there is a discoverable origin to the phrase **to cut a voluntary** (that seems to be British understatement/irony with its origins in the jargon of the British military of the 19th century) the following (OED) is probably a good candidate.

> **Voluntary (n.)**
>
> **I.2.b. A musical piece or movement played or sung spontaneously or of one's free choice,** esp. by way of prelude to a more elaborate piece, song, etc.
>
> 1598 Preludio, a proheme in musicke, a voluntary before the song. *J.
> Florio, Worlde of Wordes*
>
> a1753 Something in the nature of a flourish, or of a voluntary before
> the tune. *R. Newton, translation of Theophrastus, Characters (1754)
> 7*
>
> 1848 Sitting down to the piano, she rattled away a triumphant
> voluntary on the keys. *W. M. Thackeray, Vanity Fair xlviii. 432*

Comment: Explains the collocation, but not why _'voluntary'_ itself was used for "an unwarranted fall."

Comment: @Heartspring The fall was not warranted by an exterior agency...

Comment: Your definition of "unwarranted" is not the right one. It means "unnecessary, avoidable, unjustified" not "unsanctioned".

Comment: @TimR I respectfully disagree. It is closer to "unjustified". And the justification is the exterior agency.

Comment: I was just adding "unjustified" as you were typing, but not in the sense of "lacking permission" which is the direction you're going in, but in the sense of "lacking factual basis".

Comment: What would it mean to say that someone had been given permission or authority to fall off his horse?

Comment: @TimR I am not willing to continue this discussion as you seem to be insisting on ignorance. If you feel the answer is lacking, vote it down or ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you. We still have "cut a fine figure". My paper OED has meanings of 'voluntary' that are closer to 'preventable', but does not contain the horse reference. A fall from a horse could cause serious injury, so perhaps the jocularity is whistling past the graveyard.

Comment: Thus, it seems to mean when the rider falls from the horse _intentionally_, but there may be more: perhaps the rider considered it better than hitting his head on a tree limb. It's an interesting expression.

Comment: @Greybeard I don't know what you meant by saying that I am "insisting on ignorance" when I asked you explain what it would mean to say that someone had been given permission to fall off his horse. I thought I was giving you the opportunity to explain your reasoning there, but since you don't wish to do so, I will oblige with a downvote.

Comment: @Heartspring: I think there is a hint in the citation of 1883 that some soldiers may have voluntarily taken a fall, I imagine favoring a minor injury over the risk of death. It would be great to have further confirmation, though.

Comment: @TimR I could not, and still cannot, understand why you remark "*someone had been given permission to fall off his horse.*" If it helps, neither can I. This forced interpretation that creates a nonsense phrase is so contrary that I cannot even begin to answer it. Do you understand the idea of "agency"? (I'm assuming that you are a native English speaker.)

Comment: @MatthieuM. *there is a hint in the citation of 1883 that some soldiers may have voluntarily taken a fall, I imagine favoring a minor injury over the risk of death.* Exactly!

Comment: @Greybeard Yes, I'm a native speaker and I do have a grasp of the meaning of agency.  I presume you mean that there's (paradoxically) no agency involved in a "voluntary" and by "unsanctioned, unauthorized fall" you are suggesting that those meanings of **unwarranted** be extended to mean "by accident"?

Comment: @TimR "*I presume ...*" No not really. Please bear in mind that my answer is aimed at the OP. Not at you who, I assume, does not have a difficulty with "cut a voluntary".

Comment: @Greybeard Well, I'm not *certain* about the origin, though I do strongly suspect that it had something to do with an *intentionally self-inflicted* injury. The 1863 date of the attestation coincides with the very unpopular First Conscription Act, which made all men aged 20-45 eligible to be called up for military service in the US Civil War, to fight against the Confederates. There were riots in the streets of New York City because the act was regarded as unfair to the poor as it was legal to pay a fee to the government to exempt oneself, or to hire a substitute to stand in one's stead.

Comment: It is not at all clear how this collection of dictionary quotations is supposed to constitute an answer to the question. It confirms that the phrase has been around for a while, but does nothing to **explain** its origin. How did *voluntary* (noun) come to stand for something that is not at all voluntary (adjective)? That is what is puzzling about the phrase and what needs to be explained. I don't know whether the suggestions by StuartF, Yorik, and @TImR are true, but they are the kinds of things that, if true, would constitute the explanation.

Comment: I suspect the military (or maybe equestrian) community would have had some term such as 'voluntary dismount' as opposed to 'ordered dismount' when mounted troops are told to get off the horse by the CO (or a 'mandatory dismount' at some point in a skills competition).  Falling off a horse would not be an 'ordered' or 'mandatory' dismount, therefore it would be called (somewhat facetiously, sure) a 'voluntary dismount'.
I'm entirely guessing tho.

Comment: @TimR I suspect you are way off with your American references: the quotes are all of British origin and refer to British events. Can you find any early American use? I can't. In any case, first recorded date is unlikely to be the date of origin, especially as the word is not marked out in the text. As I have stated, the noun "voluntary" is simply a substantive (an adjective used as a noun.) There is unlikely to be any defining origin to this.

Comment: @Greybeard I haven't read the book but according to the US Library of Congress, the first work cited, *Border and bastille* by George A. Lawrence, was published  in New York in 1863 and is catalogued under United States--History--Civil War, 1861-1865.

Comment: (1) All the references are by British authors and (2) hunting on horseback is a very British: this suggests a British English origin. The military/hunting conflict is resolved as hunting on horseback was always good training for the military and vice versa. In addition to cut a voluntary in Green Dictionary of Jargon ((see TinFoil), there is -- 1903 Although I have ridden, when abroad, some of the worst buckjumpers that could be found in any country, I have never “cut a voluntary.” The Horsewoman: A Practical Guide to Side-Saddle Riding, 2nd. Ed By the very British Alice M. Hayes.

Comment: Again, we can stipulate, as the lawyers say, that there are later attestations where the phrase "a voluntary" (either cut or taken) occurs in hunting contexts. But to show that the phrase originated in hunting would require an attestation *predating* the 1863 quote from the Lawrence book about his trip to the States during the Civil War.  I am not disputing that the phrase became widely used in hunting, and I'm only tentatively floating the US cavalry origin as a *viable possibility* until some evidence to the contrary is found.  A cavalry origin would account for the word "voluntary".

Answer (score 3):

This is just a placeholder for an answer since I have to deal with some emergency plumbing issues at the moment.

EDIT:  I an becoming more convinced that  the origin of the phrase "cut|take a voluntary" is ultimately military. The earliest unambiguous military attestation I'd been able to find was in the context of conscripts in the US Civil War in a book written by a Brit who was visiting the States at the time (see below). But @TinfoilHat has floated in a comment below an attestation from a decade earlier, in a steeplechase context. In further support of the military origin, here is a description of a veritable "epidemic" of self-maiming in the British army from *ON
THE ENLISTING, THE DISCHARGING,
AND
THE PENSIONING OF SOLDIERS* by Henry Marshall (Edinburgh, 1839)

> The practice of maiming has been so frequent in some regiments as to appear epidemic. The author belonged to a regiment in which nine men maimed themselves in the course of six weeks and in every instance the injury was presumed to have been inflicted voluntarily. The explosion of their own muskets was the plan they invariably adopted to effect their purpose and the injury was always in a foot or a hand. They all, as may be inferred, attributed the explosion of the musket to accident and not to design, but one man who maimed himself in a necessary found much difficulty to account for his taking a loaded musket into a place of that kind. Very lately when Regiment was at Cork and about to embark for the West Indies, four of the men made their appearance with the first joint of the thumb of the right hand mutilated. Voluntary mutilation sometimes takes place under very extraordinary circumstances even during a conflict with an enemy.

From *Border and bastille* by George A. Lawrence (a Brit), which was published in New York in 1863 and is catalogued by the US Library of Congress under United States--History--Civil War, 1861-1865:

> On the outbreak of the war, volunteers enlisted
> in the Federal cavalry, who --far from being able
> to manage a horse--  could not bridle one without
> assistance; and a conscript, who could keep his
> saddle through an entire day, without "taking a
> voluntary", was considered by his fellows as a credit
> to the regiment, and almost an accomplished
> dragoon. Such a thing as a military riding-
> school has, I believe, never been thought of,
> away from West Point; the drill is simply that of
> mounted infantry. Things are better now than
> they were; a Federal cavalryman can at least sit
> saddle-fast, to receive and return a sabre-cut; there
> have been some sharp skirmishes of late, and,
> allowing for exaggeration, Averill s encounter
> with Fitzhugh Lee brought out real work on
> both sides.

By putting the phrase "taking a voluntary" in quotes, Lawrence seems to be quoting a phrase he has heard while visiting the encampments of the US Army, one not already familiar to a British audience.

In the chapter where the paragraph above appears, he is far more concerned about the way horses are treated by the northern Army than about the plight of the men. He speaks of the squalor of encampments  and the lack of *esprit du corps* among the lower ranks of soldiers, the result of which is a high rate of mortality for the horses:

> That utter absence of
> *esprit du corps* and soldierly self-respect, has cost the Federal treasury many millions; nor will the drain ever cease till "re-mounts"
> shall be no more needed.
>
> The foregoing remarks apply exclusively to
> the *tenue* of the privates and non-commissioned officers; those of
> superior rank that I met were tolerably correct, both in dress and
> equipment; several, indeed, were mounted on really powerful chargers,
> and rode them not amiss, though with a seat as unprofessional as can
> be conceived.

P.S.  Evidence of the phrase origin would be an attestation (ideally additional attestations) for the posited explanation. We know the phrase is used in hunting; slang dictionaries before Green's have glossed the phrase as "to fall off a horse while hunting" and attestations can be found. But the earliest attestation so far is a cavalry context. Did the phrase begin in hunting or cavalry? And if the latter, was it a long-standing British cavalry phrase predating 1863 or was it coined as American military jargon or American military slang? In the same chapter, George A. Lawrence does indeed refer to US military jargon ("re-mounts"). So it is not implausible that he was citing two terms he had heard used in the US Army on his visit to the States. The question is open -- from a lexicographical perspective.

P.P.S. You might be surprised by how often you'd hear the word "bespoke" these days here in the good old US of A.  The borrowing is a two-way street.

Comment: *George A. Lawrence (a Brit), … “taking a voluntary”*. A Brit using a British phrase that is placed in inverted commas for an American audience? Not surprising. Surely this suggests that he heard it in the UK and was introducing it to a foreign audience? The phrase is entirely unrelated to the politics of the day. Lawrence was well versed in British military jargon *Lawrence seems to be quoting a phrase he has heard while visiting the encampments of the US Army* Ockham's Razor: surely he's introducing British military jargon that he already knew. Is there any other example of US use?

Comment: So "to cut a voluntary" is, perhaps "to act in the fashion of a volunteer who cannot remain mounted on their horse"; perhaps recognising that the target is a skilled rider for whom this is not usual behaviour.

Comment: @Greybeard  Your alternative reading of the quotation marks around the phrase, introducing a British phrase to an American audience, is not implausible, though from what I've read in the book so far it doesn't seem addressed to an American audience. Do you have a British attestation that predates the 1863 attestation, showing it to be British military jargon already in use?

Comment: [But we already know it comes from hunting.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dictionary_of_Jargon_Routledge_Revivals/4QAjAQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Dictionary%20of%20Jargon%22%20%22Jonathon%20Green%22%20%22cut%20a%20voluntary%22&pg=PA152&printsec=frontcover) I mean, I wouldn't argue with Jonathon Green. The question remains how *voluntary* came to relate to falling off a horse.

Comment: @TinfoilHat  You can find lots of things in books. Without an attestation, it's just one man's opinion. It could be right, or it could be wrong.

Comment: I daresay [Jonathon Green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathon_Green)’s “opinion” is better than anything you‘re going to get here.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Appeals to authority don't cut it; what is required is *evidence*. I've floated a theory that requires further evidence to support it.  Green hasn't offered attestations and he doesn't say the  phrase originated in hunting in any case.

Comment: @TimR *Appeals to authority don't cut it; what is required is evidence.* Please define what, for you, would be "evidence". Would we need a recording of the person in the process of coining the phrase?

Comment: @Greybeard:  Evidence of a phrase *origin* would be an attestation for the posited explanation. We know the phrase is used in hunting; slang dictionaries before Green's have glossed the phrase as "to fall off a horse while hunting" and attestations can be found. But the earliest attestation so far is a *cavalry* context. Did the phrase began in hunting or cavalry? And if the latter, was it a long-standing British cavalry phrase predating 1863 or was it coined as American military jargon? In the same chapter,  George A. Lawrence does indeed refer to US military jargon ("re-mounts").

Comment: This requirement is the very basis of lexicography "on historical principles".

Comment: "begin", not "began". Too late to correct.

Comment: @TimR *Evidence of a phrase origin would be an attestation for the posited explanation.* No. If you are consistent, then you would dismiss that as an appeal to authority. *But the earliest attestation so far is a cavalry context. Did the phrase began in hunting or cavalry?* For the OP's purpose it started with people falling off horses when they shouldn't. Hunting and the cavalry have been linked from time immemorial.

Comment: @Greybeard Yes. It would not be an "appeal to authority" but an example of use "in the wild". And if you don't distinguish between cavalry and hunting, there's not much use discussing this with you, is there?

Comment: In the paragraph prior, the author is literally talking about hunting jumpers: “there are few [horses], north of the Potomac, that I should like to ride at four feet of stiff timber.... It is very different in the South, where many men... would hold their own tolerable in England, over a fair hunting country...” In the subject paragraph, volunteers can’t bridle their horses and (involuntary) draftees who don't fall off their horses are considered accomplished. The only question left, really, is how *a volunteer* came to mean *a fall off a horse*.

Comment: cf. [*cut a voluntary over some timber*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Baily_s_Magazine_of_Sports_and_Pastimes/hp5GAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22voluntary%22%20%22timber%22%20%22horse%22%20%22jump%22%20%22hunt%22&pg=PA369&printsec=frontcover) (1876)

Comment: @TinfoilHat I've already conceded that there are attestations *post* 1863 where the context is non-cavalry (e.g. hunting and riding that simulates the sorts of jumps that happen in hunting). That one is from 1876. To support the view that the phrase "taking a voluntary" originated in hunting, attestations using that phrase with a hunting context *predating* 1863 are needed.

Comment: Just logging this here for future research... [**1854**](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_New_sporting_magazine/LY8EAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0): *“What! for a gallop with hounds, Sir, to be ridden over with the Pytchley? or to be abused by some Squire Slowman, for a voluntary over a gate? We had a gallop yesterday.”*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Looks promising.